# leagacy ms access database with some unreadable fields

Tags: ms-access

[image: database filed as it is in a visual basic 6 datagrid]

I have an ms access database that have some fields not readable. The ms accesss is microsoft accesss 97 and in cbf format, when I connect to the database it comes out as in the picture.
Some field are readable some are not.

My question is how do I get all the fields readable again so I can work with it

thanks

Comment: Can the access app read the fields? Do you have the source?

Comment: From Googling, it seems that CBF is some kind of image format. Seems like you need to find a converter, or go to the documentation of the format and write the converter yourself. Not a fun task! I think you should repost your question cast as a question about converting CBF data to some other image format, because that's the issue here. Getting the data out of your Access database is the trivial part of the problem.

Comment: yes,i have the source i just can not make out why so fields are readable while some are not.i need to explain this problem i just do not know what to say???or how to solve it .

Comment: When you bring up the table in design view, what type of column is the ”questions"? If it is a blob (or ole object), then some "code" in the application pulls out the data and formats it as an question based on some coding structure. So, it perhaps not that the question is un-readable, but that format is what the program requires.

So, if that column is memo, or ole object, then you need to look at the code to see how this data is parsed out or how it is dealt with.

Comment: Albert D. Kallal you are right just checked in the design view and the column is memo. i now have something to start with. Thanks,could love to accept ur answer. please rewrite this comment as answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It may simply be that the fields have been intentionally obfuscated and you need a specific application to see them. Do you know the history of the database?

Comment: no i dont, i guess so as well any any chance to deobfuscating it . i really need to get my hand on the data to enable rewrite the app